# Navigation Component transition animation doesn't work properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-editor

In `MainActivity.kt`, I have methods to change its `Fragment`.

Here is a method for going to `SettingActivity.kt`

```
    override fun startSetting() {
        Timber.d("startSetting()")
        Toast.makeText(activity, "startSetting()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Navigation.findNavController(mView).navigate(R.id.action_initFragment_to_settingFragment)
    }
```

this is `nav_graph.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/initFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/initFragment"
        android:name="come.example.view.main.fragment.InitFragment"
        android:label="fragment_init"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_init">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_initFragment_to_settingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_initFragment_to_webFragment"
            app:destination="@id/webFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />
        <action ... />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

This is `enter_from_right.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Here's `exit_to_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

This is `none.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

At the first time, I used `fragment id` in `MainActivity.kt` to change the fragments. However, it seemed like it can't find the destination correctly. So, I used `action id` instead of it. And It seems work. However, enter/exit works incorrectly. But pop works fine.

When I used the default `none` option in Navigation Editor, It just shows white screen and then change to the later screen. And when I used my custom `none.xml` It just changes without any animation(maybe just blinking)

What's wrong with that?

Comment: I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351043/how-to-make-slide-animation-with-a-fixed-screen-and-new-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make slide animation with a fixed screen and new screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351043/how-to-make-slide-animation-with-a-fixed-screen-and-new-screen)

Comment: Hi any luck finding solution Please guide